# Nothing happening on calling dismiss method of AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-phone-call

basically i have 2 classes, "ShowAlert" and "CallReceiver", the alerts creates without any problems, but when i try to call the method "alertDisplay.dismissAlert();" it just doesen't happen anything, the alert remains there and the console isn't showing any error, searching on internet for some days isn't the answer, i didn't find anything useful on internet for resolving my problem

These are the classes, thanks for the help

CallReceiver.java

```
package com.numbertracker;

import android.app.KeyguardManager;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat;

//BroadcastReceiver serve ad avere tutte quelle funzioni per controllare chiamate e altro in arrivo
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

     ShowAlert alertDisplay = new ShowAlert();
    //onReceive serve a prendere le informazioni delle chiamate a seconda dello stato in cui si trovamo, di seguito piu info
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent)
    {

        try {
            //state è una variabile che serve a sapere appunto in che stato è il telefono, bloccato? sta squillando? sei in chiamata? ecc.
            String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); //serve a trasformare la stringa number in un Text visto che Toast non vuole String
            EDITED, NOW AS A PRIVATE VARIABLE ShowAlert alertDisplay = new ShowAlert();
            KeyguardManager myKM = (KeyguardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);

            if(!intent.hasExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER))
                return;
            if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                //Log.e("Zed", "ringing");
                String number = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                sb.append(number);
                number = sb.toString();

                if( myKM.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode()) {
                    showNotification(context,"bla bla",intent);
                } else {
                    alertDisplay.display("bla bla",context);
                }

                //Toast.makeText(context,number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
                alertDisplay.dismissAlert();
                //Log.e("Zed", "offhook");
                //Toast.makeText(context, "Didn't answer the call", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                alertDisplay.dismissAlert();
                //Log.e("Zed", "idle");
                //Toast.makeText(context, "Call in hold state", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void showNotification(Context context, String title, String body, Intent intent) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        int notificationId = 1;
        String channelId = "channel-01";
        String channelName = "LockScreen";
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                    channelId, channelName, importance);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                0,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build());
    }

}
```

ShowAlert.java

```
package com.numbertracker;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Build;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class ShowAlert {

    //funzione che puo essere richiamata quando si vuole per mostrare un alert, ho creato una classe apposita in caso
    //si volessero aggiungere piu alert senza intasare main o altre funzioni, cosi puo essere chiamata ovunque

    private AlertDialog alert;

    public void display(String title, Context context)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setTitle("NumberTracker Alert")
                .setMessage(title)
                .setCancelable(false)
                //.setPositiveButton("Block Number", (dialog, which) -> Toast.makeText(context, "Selected Option: YES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show())
                .setNegativeButton("Dismiss", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { // define the 'Cancel' button
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        alert = builder.create();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            alert.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY);
        } else {
            alert.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
        }
        alert.show();

    }

    public void dismissAlert(){
        if(alert != null){
            alert.dismiss();
        }
    }


}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.numbertracker">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.NumberTracker">

        <receiver android:name=".CallReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: `ShowAlert alertDisplay = new ShowAlert();` – Every time `onReceive()` runs, you're creating a new instance of `ShowAlert`, so the one that you called `display("bla bla",context)` on is not the same one that you're calling `dismissAlert()` on. That one never had `display()` called on it, so its `alert` is still null when you call its `dismissAlert()`.

Comment: omg i'm so stupid, anyway i tried putting ShowAlert alertDisplay = new ShowAlert(); as a private variable of the class but it still doesen't work

Comment: I guess I never knew this, but setting the window type like that, with the necessary permission, allows `Dialog`s to be shown from a static Receiver. Interesting. Anyhoo, sorry, disregard my previous comment. If you do indeed have this set up as I now think you do – i.e., by statically registering `CallReceiver` with a `<receiver>` element in your manifest – then issue is still the same thing: multiple instances of `ShowAlert`. Receiver classes registered in the manifest are instantiated anew for each broadcast, so the instance that ran for `RINGING` is not the same as that for `OFFHOOK`.

Comment: sorry i forgot to put my manifest as well, i added it above on the main question, i already had receiver in it

Comment: Yeah, I figured. I was saying, that setup still has the same basic issue, in that you're ending up with multiple `ShowAlert` instances, because a new `CallReceiver` instance is created for each broadcast; e.g., one instance for `RINGING`, and a separate one for `OFFHOOK`.

Comment: Oh thank you now i got it, i have to try to fix this but at least i know the problem, i don't know how i didn't figure it out before hahaha

Answer (score -1):

Don't call `alert.dismiss()`. Call `builder.dismiss()`.
Because `AlertDialog.Builder` has command `dismiss()`, not `alert`.

Right code:

`builder.dismiss()`, and define `AlertDialog.Builder builder` in your class outside `display()` function, so that `dismissAlert()` function can also use it to dismiss the Dialog.

Comment: Sorry but this isn't how alerts work in android, you create the builder and set all the attributes you need, then you set AlertDialog abc = builder.build(); until now the alert doesen't exists...

Comment: Try this code, this worked for me. Also, in the onCreate method, it is initialized. So what's the problem?